# Discord PY Bot not responding to an event

Tags: url-rewriting, discord, discord.py

I have this bot that when it detects that a user has written a certain message in a certain channel, it will send a message then delete the user's message and its own message.

I wrote the exact same function to do the same thing in another channel and it works just fine.
I checked the bot's permissions and it can send messages in the channel,
here is the code:

the `for` loop is for searching for a specific text.

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    text = message.content
    chann = message.channel.id
    yes = False
    for strf in comms:
        if text.startswith(strf):
            yes = True
    if yes and (message.author.id != 769302967803183124) and (message.channel.id == 331562608467509249):
        print(message.author.id)
        msg = await message.channel.send('mech lahne tekteb el commands ye bhim')
        await message.delete()
        await asyncio.sleep(4)
        await msg.delete()
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have two similar events on the same file?

Comment: What exactly is the problem here, are you saying that it works in one channel and doesn't work in another channel? Your problem might be the check, try printing `(text.startswith(strf)` and check if the channel returns True. if not, then your channel name doesn't start with strf and you have to change it. Can't see any other problem here

Comment: I fixed it. The problem was that I used two events. For some reason two on_messge can't be used separately.oh and the starts with works fine